# Interpolating the position of pixels within a shape, given the movement of the shape's vertices

Tags: image, interpolation, vertex

I'm trying to write an algorithm that can mock-simulate the earth's plate tectonics, given two 'snapshots' of the position of tectonic plates in history.

For example we have the image used to define the first snapshot:

[image]

and the one used for the second snapshot, in which the continent has moved east, rotated counter clockwise, and deformed a bit:

[image]

Each coloured pixel represents a vertex on the shape, which is registered when the image is read by my program.

Each purple pixel is a tile on the plate. I want these tiles to move with the vertices.

My original plan was an algorithm like this one:

1. For each purple tile T in initial plate P1:
2. Get the vector distances between T and P1's vertices.
3. Add each vector distance to that vertex's position in plate P2.
4. Take the average of all the resulting positions. This will hopefully tell you where T ought to sit within P2's vertices, given its position within P1's vertices.

See below: taking the vector differences of T in P1, applying those to P2, and taking the average position.
[image]

But this does not seem to work. Running this interpolation, all tiles move uniformly:[image]

Does anyone know how to do what I need?